# Why can't I hear my voice from another subscriber SIP?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sip

Using this code, I manage to dial, from subscriber A to subscriber B, but I cannot transfer my voice. If I understand correctly, I need to send an rtp session in a request when calling another subscriber. But I don't understand how to do this in Xamarin. the library I use `sipsorcery` is the only library that works for xamamrin, its and it's free. I tried various libraries for about a week and settled on this one. Its only problem is that it is Windows oriented. I read the developer's answer to this question and as far as I understood with xamamrin, it is possible to send a voice and call, here is their answer to a similar question https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery/issues/220. As a result, I came to the conclusion that I cannot form an RTP session on xamarin, but I can call.

As in developer tests:

```
IPTransport sipTransport = new SIPTransport();
SIPUDPChannel udpChannel = new SIPUDPChannel(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
sipTransport.AddSIPChannel(udpChannel);
SIPUserAgent ua = new SIPUserAgent(sipTransport, null);

IMediaSession dummySession = new RtpAudioSession(new DummyAudioOptions { AudioSource = 
DummyAudioSourcesEnum.SineWave }, new List<SDPMediaFormatsEnum> { SDPMediaFormatsEnum.PCMU });
Task.Run(async () => await ua.Call("time@67.222.131.147", null, null, dummySession));
```

Here is my code:

```
public class CallViewModel
    {
        string USERNAME = "1001";
        string PASSWORD = "1234";
        string DOMAIN = "192.168.0.105";
        int EXPIRY = 120;
        protected MediaRecorder recorder;

        SIPTransport sipTransport = new SIPTransport();
     
        public CallViewModel()
        {
            SIPRegistrationUserAgent regUserAgent = new SIPRegistrationUserAgent(sipTransport, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DOMAIN, EXPIRY);
            regUserAgent.RegistrationFailed += Failed;
            regUserAgent.RegistrationTemporaryFailure += Failure;
            regUserAgent.RegistrationRemoved += RegRemove;
            regUserAgent.RegistrationSuccessful += Success;
            regUserAgent.Start();
            myCall();
        }
        public  async Task myCall()
        {

          
             string DESTINATION = "192.168.0.105";
          string hostName = Dns.GetHostName(); // Retrive the Name of HOST  

          string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
          System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(myIP);
         

          // Create a SIP user agent client that can be used to initiate calls to external SIP devices and place a call.

          SIPUDPChannel udpChannel = new SIPUDPChannel(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
          sipTransport.AddSIPChannel(udpChannel);
          SIPClientUserAgent uac = new SIPClientUserAgent(sipTransport);

          SIPCallDescriptor callDescriptor = new SIPCallDescriptor("1001", "1234", "sip:1002@192.168.0.105", "<sip:1001@192.168.0.105>", null, null, null, null, SIPCallDirection.Out, "application/sdp", null, null);
          uac.Call(callDescriptor);
             
        }

        private void Success(SIPURI obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void RegRemove(SIPURI obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Failure(SIPURI arg1, string arg2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Failed(SIPURI arg1, string arg2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Perhaps there are some code examples

Comment: You might have better success writing code in the Android-specific project.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, Why this comment? I am writing under Xamarin.Forms and at the moment I am trying to solve the problem here

Comment: I understand. A Xamarin Form solution has multiple projects. One project is for cross-platform "Xamarin Forms" code. That is the project with .xaml files. There are also projects , one for each "platform" you are building for. I have not found any cross-platform code for sipsorcery. You gave a link to code someone got working on Android. Try that code in your `MyProjectName.Android` project. If you get it working there, that would be a start. Then to access from the cross-platform project, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve This code works in MyProject.Android and is the same in general code. The problem is that I cannot capture the voice and transfer it to another subscriber. because sipsorcery is windows oriented. Because of this, I cannot capture the voice.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any more ideas. I misunderstood - I thought that code wasn't working at all. Did you open an issue at that sipsorcery github? They may be the only ones who can help.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, I opened the question, sipsorcery